# Am I missing something? FormData and .get from FormGroup

Tags: angular, typescript

I have some issues where I don't really know where the problem in the code is. I've searched a bit on it but no luck.

I've been trying to make a contact form using Angular Reactive Forms and with HttpClient to make the post requests and such. Has anyone got any input in regards to this? Problem is located at the FormData.append part. Error message I get is "Object is possibly 'null'." for the three formData.appends I use.

Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MessageService } from 'primeng/api';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-contact',
  templateUrl: './contact.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./contact.component.scss']
})
export class ContactComponent implements OnInit {

  contactForm: FormGroup;
  submitted = false;
  isLoading = false;
  name: FormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required]);
  email: FormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);
  message: FormControl = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(256)]);
  honeypot: FormControl = new FormControl('');

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private messageService: MessageService, private http: HttpClient) {
    this.contactForm = this.fb.group({
      name: this.name,
      email: this.email,
      message: this.message,
      honeypot: this.honeypot
    });
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  onSubmit() {
    if (this.contactForm.status == 'VALID' && this.honeypot.value == '') {
      this.contactForm.disable();
      const formData:FormData = new FormData();
      formData.append('name', this.contactForm.get('name').value);
      formData.append('email', this.contactForm.get('email').value);
      formData.append('message', this.contactForm.get('message').value);
      this.isLoading = true;
      this.submitted = false;
      this.http.post('URL FROM GOOGLE HERE', formData).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          if (response == 'success') {
            this.messageService.add({
              severity: 'success',
              summary: 'Success',
              detail: 'Den mail er blevet sendt.'
            });
          } else {
            this.messageService.add({
              severity: 'error',
              summary: 'Error',
              detail: 'Afsendelsen af din mail fik en fejl.'
            });
          }
          this.contactForm.enable();
          this.submitted = true;
          this.isLoading = false;
          console.log(response);
        },
        (error) => {
          this.messageService.add({
            severity: 'error',
            summary: 'Error',
            detail: 'En fejl er opstået, prøv og genindlæs siden igen eller prøv senere.'
          });
          this.contactForm.enable();
          this.submitted = true;
          this.isLoading = false;
          console.log(error);
        }
      );
    }
  }
}
```

HTML for the component

```
<section id="contact">
    <div class="main">
        <div class="text"> <!-- tittle og under tekst -->
            <h1>Kontakt os</h1>
            <p> Har du bruge for noget hjælp? <br>
                Er der nogen fejl, som du kan se eller <br>
                ville du bare i kontakt med os? <br>
                Skriv endelig til os.
            </p>
        </div>
        <form [formGroup]="contactForm" method="POST" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(contactForm.value)">
            <div class="input_warp">
                <span class="p-float-label">
                    <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="name">
                    <label for="name">Navn</label>
                    <p-message severity="error" text="Du skal skrive dit navn ind."
                        *ngIf="!contactForm.controls['name'].valid && contactForm.controls['name'].dirty"></p-message>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="input_warp"> <!-- skriv din email -->
                <span class="p-float-label">
                    <input type="email" class="p-inputtext" pInputText formControlName="email">
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                </span>
                <p-message severity="error" text="Du skal skrive din mail ind."
                    *ngIf="!contactForm.controls['email'].valid && contactForm.controls['email'].dirty"></p-message>
            </div>
            <input>
            <div class="input_warp">
                <textarea rows="10" cols="30" class="textarea-resize" pInputTextarea name="message"
                    placeholder="Besked her..."></textarea>
            </div>
            <div> <!-- send besked -->
                <button class="button">Send besked</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

App Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { WelcomeComponent } from './before-login/welcome/welcome.component';
import { AboutComponent } from './before-login/welcome/components/about/about.component';
import { ContactComponent } from './before-login/welcome/components/contact/contact.component';
import { NavComponent } from './before-login/welcome/components/nav/nav.component';
import { SigninComponent } from './before-login/welcome/components/signin/signin.component';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { InputTextModule } from 'primeng/inputtext';
import { TooltipModule } from 'primeng/tooltip';
import { InputTextareaModule } from 'primeng/inputtextarea';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';
import { AngularFireAuthModule } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestoreModule } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { environment } from '../environments/environment';
import { NgAuthService } from './auth/auth.service';
import { PasswordModule } from 'primeng/password';
import { ToastModule } from 'primeng/toast';
import { ForgotPasswordComponent } from './before-login/forgot-password/forgot-password.component';
import { EmailVerificationComponent } from './before-login/email-verification/email-verification.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './after-login/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './before-login/welcome/components/signup/signup.component';
import { LazyLoadImageModule } from 'ng-lazyload-image';
import { UserProfileComponent } from './after-login/user-profile/user-profile.component';
import { MessageModule } from 'primeng/message';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    WelcomeComponent,
    AboutComponent,
    ContactComponent,
    NavComponent,
    SigninComponent,
    ForgotPasswordComponent,
    EmailVerificationComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    UserProfileComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    InputTextModule,
    TooltipModule,
    InputTextareaModule,
    FormsModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    AngularFireAuthModule,
    AngularFirestoreModule,
    PasswordModule,
    ToastModule,
    LazyLoadImageModule,
    MessageModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  providers: [NgAuthService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: Could you please paste in the complete stacktrace of the error that you're getting?

Comment: Not able to send you it. As my live server can't see the website. I can send what I see on my vs:c terminal?

Comment: Currently getting "Cannot GET /home", so that is why I can't access it.

Comment: Can you create a Stackblitz example?

Comment: Sure. I can do that. Just a sec then

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sesffn?file=src/app/contact/contact.component.ts @Rajat I should have it setup. Now I just get a different error.

Comment: maybe adding the null-safe operator ? `this.contactForm.get('name')?.value`

Comment: Well, the error that I get I don't see on stackblitz.
Link to the image from my Visual Code Terminal: https://ibb.co/fx4Rm3b

Comment: @Random I have already done that. Nothing. It doesn't work with the null-safe op. I tried it before as I read something about it.

Comment: Maybe [assignment-assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) then: `this.contactForm.get('name')!.value`

Comment: "Forbidden non null assertion (no-non-null-assertion)" well not an error anymore, but a warning now. I don't know if this can be prevented?

Comment: Errors on your screenshot also show you did not import the ReactiveFormModule. You also don't need `method` on your `<form>` tag, since you don't use the native HTML submit.

Comment: Yeah I forgot that somehow. That I have done now though and that error is gone.

Comment: Well I tested it. I don't think it can get past the formData part. I guess I will do some debugging.

Comment: What's the issue that you are having? I don't see any errors on Stackblitz. Also, nothing happens when I click the submit button.

Comment: @Rajat I have provided my answer to my issue below. I had made a new post and got some better help that explained it a little better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with a little help elsewhere. Seems I firstly forgot to import Reactive Forms, as I only had Forms imported.

Then I had some issues in regards to `formData.append`. I found a better solution to the coding I had done in that part and it works good. I also had some issue where I could not use `response["result"]`. But also found the solution for that with `(response: any) =>`
I don't know if I had typed something wrong on the form part, but it works now after copying something from StackBlitz.

StackBlitz that has everything working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2yiyr3?file=src/app/contact/contact.component.ts

Comment: Your link is not working. How did you fix this??

Answer (score 0):

why you use "FormData"? you can simple send a simple object, e.g.

```
  this.http.post('...',
      {
        name:this.contactForm.value.name,
        email:this.contactForm.value.email,
        message:this.contactForm.value.message,
      }
    )
```

Comment: Well the tutorial I followed in regards to using google sheets scripting to send email. Had used FormData for the task. Sure you could probably have used a different way like the one you have provided. But seems like the way I have done it now makes it work perfect.